# how to save ArrayList into internal Storage

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, inventory

I'm trying to make an inventory apps to save item by item into internal storage. Here is my layout. The problem is it possible to save arraylist into document text file / other internal storage? Because fos.write(listitem.getBytes()); should be in Int. Here is my code from Activity2

```html
package com.example.java;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String extraint = "1";
    public static final String namabarang = "2";
    public static final String jumlahstock ="3";
    public static final String FILE_NAME="example.txt";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onBtnClick(View view){


        TextView plain1 = findViewById(R.id.NamaBarang);
        TextView plain2 = findViewById(R.id.SKU);
        TextView plain3 = findViewById(R.id.JumlahStok);
        TextView plain4 = findViewById(R.id.HargaBeli);
        TextView plain5 = findViewById(R.id.HargaJual);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity3.class);
        String x = "1";

        String text = plain1.getText().toString();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        Item m1 = new Item("a","1");
        Item m2 = new Item("b","2");
        Item m3 = new Item("c","3");
        ArrayList<Item> listitem =  new ArrayList<>();

        listitem.add(m1);
        listitem.add(m2);
        listitem.add(m3);
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(listitem.getBytes());

            Toast.makeText(this,"Saved to" +getFilesDir() + "/" + FILE_NAME,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(fos != null){
                try{
                    fos.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        intent.putExtra(extraint,x);
        intent.putExtra(FILE_NAME,text);
        intent.putExtra(namabarang,plain1.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra(jumlahstock,plain3.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);



    }
}
```

Here is another code from Activity 3

```html
package com.example.java;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.renderscript.ScriptGroup;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String Tag = "MainAcitivity3";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        Log.d(Tag, "onCreate: Started.");
        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String[] barang = new String[20];
        String[] jumlah = new String[20];
        ArrayList<Item> itemlist = new ArrayList<Item>();

        int loop=0;
        barang[loop] = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity2.namabarang);
        jumlah[loop] = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity2.jumlahstock);
        loop++;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            fis = openFileInput(MainActivity2.FILE_NAME);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String text;

            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(text).append("\n");
            }


        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(fis!=null){
                try{
                    fis.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        String result=sb.toString();
        for(int i=0;i<loop;i++) {
            Item sparepart = new Item(result, result);

            itemlist.add(sparepart);
        }
        PersonListAdapter adapter = new PersonListAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout,itemlist);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        String number = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity2.extraint);
        if(number != null) {
            FrameLayout lay = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frames);
            if (number.equals("1")) {
                lay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {

            }
        }
        else{}

    }

    public void onBtnClick (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }



}
```

The apps supposed to save one item by item into the internal storage which where i try to utilize array to save the into the internal storage, but it it possible to save and read array to internal storage?

Comment: `fos.write(listitem.getBytes()); should be in Int.` You probably want a Serializable object and an ObjectOutputStream, or use `XMLEncoder`.  Please clarify if these can work for you and if not, why not.

Comment: Yes i know that should be int, is there any other solutions?